# Find questions I voted to close

Tags: support, vote-to-close

I'm not sure if there's a way to do this, as I'm new to 3k reputation and might just be missing it - so if it exists I apologize.

I voted to close a question and started to write a comment on the question to suggest improvements, but I accidentally closed my tab prior to submitting the comment.  I cannot find the question any longer to provide the comment, so my question was is there a way to find the questions I've voted to close?  Pre 3k reputation I could easily find "flagged" questions, but I'm not finding that option any longer, as even when I "flag" questions, they now show up as close votes.

Additionally, if I *were* to find the question that I had voted to close, should the question be improved is there a way to retract the vote?

Comment: @HansPassant Are you saying that taking the time to improve a question or answer is wasting time? I'm not really understanding your comment.

Comment: @HansPassant I'm not sure if there was a misunderstanding or not on my question, but this wasn't about me "flaunting my 3k rep" (if that's what you're implying) to the question asker.  It was about how to find a question I had voted to close (that I had actually flagged) - as flags perform differently on the site once you hit 3k reputation it seems..  Is the point of the site not to provide quality questions/answers in a way that could help not only the asker, but future askers as well?  That was what I was trying to get at, provide a comment to the poster to help them with a better question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On your user profile, the [right-most tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2312877/kritner?tab=votes) is called **"Votes"**, visible only to you.  Your closure votes are visible there in reverse-chronological order, along with all your other votes.

It looks like this:

[image: Screenshot of tab on user profile]

You may always retract your close vote whether or not the post was improved, by clicking again on the "close" link and then **"Retract Close Vote"**. You may of course also vote to reopen a closed question if you feel reopening is warranted if it has already received 5 close votes and been placed on hold.

Comment: ah thanks.  And now that I see and have found the question I can see that you can in fact retract your vote to close flag.  Thanks!